# where do I host my sqlite3 database?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, hosting

I'm building an iPhone app which uses the sqlite3 library - are there any special requirements for hosting the database itself since its using sqlite3? Can I host it on one of my GoDaddy accounts for example? I get like 25 free databases with my current account with them but I'm just wondering if the SQL databases they can host will work or if they need to be sqlite3 format specifically...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the database file to the `Library/Caches` folder instead of hosting it online, unless you have a specific reason to keep it online.

Comment: Actually, that depends entirely on what's in the DB and how big it is.  If it's totally "personal" data -- not shared somehow with other phones or external apps -- and less than maybe 10mb then the phone is a good choice.

Comment: For most of the purposes I can think of, bundling it with the app works best. If a database needs to be updated from an online source, it just needs the sqlite file, not a database server. For the OP's purposes, I'd say either bundling with the app, or developing a simple REST interface is best.

Comment: Yep, if using a remote DB then a REST interface to it is far superior to a remote SQL interface.

Comment: OK, the app does need to interface with a database thats constantly updating - which is why I can't store the database locally (meaning bundle it with the app.) You guys are talking about using "REST" - but I don't know what that is :-(   What is it? How do you use it?  Any info or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @sirab333 it's a way to make a web service. For example, when you interact with Instagram, they have a web service to get updates. Here's an explanation of REST with PHP: http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Comment: Also, you might find it easier to use MySQL if you have an online database. It's more widely supported in the web world.

Comment: @nevan - I'm confused about MySQL vs. sqlite3.  The book I'm using says the iPhone uses sqlite3 to work with databases. So are MySQL and sqlite3 totally different things, or is one a subset of the other, or are they different protocols or something or....? Ultimately, the goal is to set up a database on one of my GoDaddy accounts and have my app access/interface with it via webServices.  So what I need to know is: (1) what sort of database to use and have sitting on the server (2) how/where to access it

Comment: You'll have to check GoDaddy to see what kind of database they have available. It's probably MySQL. For a database _on_ the iPhone, you can only use SQLite. I can't help much with setting up an online interface, but you should read about REST interfaces online to learn it.